# How to enforce non-overlapping ranges in RDBMS (transaction safe)?

Tags: sql, transactions, range, rdbms, overlapping

I recently discovered postgres exclude constraints, which enable excatly what I asked (well, at least for time ranges for now, since a number range type doesn't exist yet).

From what I understand oracle and other RDBMS don't have an equivalent feature to exclude constraints. So your only chance to make inserts into such a table transaction safe is to lock the table? Or is there another way?

edit: (@ Clodoaldo)
postgres does use row level locks when two transactions insert conflicting records. My question is: If a RDBMS doesn't feature exclude constraints, I think you have no other chance than to lock the whole table if you want non-overlapping ranges and transaction safety - is that correct? Or is there a way that I'm not aware of?

At work, several times I had to design tables with non-overlapping ranges. I didn't know any transaction-safe way to enforce data consistency in the database. When I read about the exclusion constraints, I thought it solved that problem, but it's non-standard, so my boss isn't very keen on using it.

Comment: I had to read the manual to be introduced to exclusion constraints, but I'm still confused about your question. Could you elaborate on it? Doesn't the lock also happens when inserting in a table with a exclusion constraint?

Comment: I don't know about that. I thought postgres somehow used the index that's necessary for the exclude constraint to throw an error when the second of two conflicting inserting transactions commits. Over the next days I'm going to experiment with exclude constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you use PostgreSQL it provides several time range types and [non-overlapping unique constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT) for them.